# MySQL Join Table Duplicate Values

Tags: mysql, sql

**Tables**

Name: _close_checks

```
+-------------+-------+---------+------------+
|   check_id  | Net   | Gross   |    Tax     |
+-------------+-------+---------+------------+
|       11111 | 100   | 210     |    10      |
|       22222 | 200   | 220     |    20      |
|       33333 | 200   | 300     |    100     |
+-------------+-------+---------+------------+
```

Name : _close_payment_type

```
+-------------+--------------+----------------+
|   check_id  | payment_type | payment_amount |
+-------------+--------------+----------------+
|       11111 |    Cash      |       110      |
|       11111 |    Visa      |       100      |
|       22222 |    Cash      |       220      | 
|       22222 |    Cash      |       300      |   
+-------------+--------------+----------------+
```

I join the tables using this code:

```
Select  *
From _close_payment_type
  Inner Join _close_checks On _close_checks.check_id = _close_payment_type.check_id
```

**Result I get:**

```
+-------------+-------+---------+------------+--------------+----------------+
|   check_id  | Net   | Gross   |    Tax     | payment_type | payment_amount |
+-------------+-------+---------+------------+--------------+----------------+
|       11111 | 100   | 210     |    10      |    Cash      |       110      |
|       11111 | 100   | 210     |    10      |    vISA      |       100      |
|       22222 | 200   | 220     |    20      |    Cash      |       220      | 
|       33333 | 200   | 300     |    100     |    Cash      |       300      |   
+-------------+-------+---------+------------+--------------+----------------+
```

You see duplicated NET - Gross - Tax value for check number 11111

**Result I Want:**

```
+-------------+-------+---------+------------+--------------+----------------+
|   check_id  | Net   | Gross   |    Tax     | payment_type | payment_amount |
+-------------+-------+---------+------------+--------------+----------------+
|       11111 | 100   | 210     |    10      |    Cash      |       110      |
|       11111 |   -   |   -     |     -      |    vISA      |       100      |
|       22222 | 200   | 220     |    20      |    Cash      |       220      | 
|       33333 | 200   | 300     |    100     |    Cash      |       300      |   
+-------------+-------+---------+------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Sorry For My Bad English, And Thanks

Comment: look up `GROUP BY`

Comment: If your question is not related to php - then the `php` and `mysqli` tags are irrelevant.

Comment: @cmorrissey that was my first thought, too, but OP doesn't want to combine rows but replace some field values if they're same...

Answer (score 0):

This is not called duplicate data since the payment type and amount are different. You can take the data and display it the way you want in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your ultimate goal, you could do something as simple as

```
Select _close_payment_type.check_id, IF(payment_type='Visa','-',Net) AS Net, IF(payment_type='Visa','-',Gross) AS Gross, IF(payment_type='Visa','-',Tax) AS Tax, payment_type, payment_amount From _close_payment_type Inner Join _close_checks On _close_checks.check_id = _close_payment_type.check_id;
```

That does cause the data to appear how you want, but may not be the best way to go.  It would be helpful to know more about the actual problem you are trying to solve.